# Port 8080 redirect troubles with Wordpress in a Vagrant VM

Tags: wordpress, vagrant, ports

So I have a problem with Wordpress running in a Vagrant VM. The VM is an Ubuntu box, precise32, running under VirtualBox. It's configured for a private network, with no specific port forwarding rules:

```
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

The VM has a basic LAMP stack, with no added config -- no virtual hosts, for example.

From the host machine I can reach standard resources on the VM via HTTP just fine: the basic index.html, or anything I care to put into subdirectories.

I have WordPress installed into /wordpress. When I try to access

```
http://192.168.33.10/wordpress
```

from a browser on the host, I get redirected to

```
http://192.168.33.10:8080/wordpress
```

Which fails, because nothing is listening there.

When I create a specific hostname for the VM and add it to my hosts /etc/hosts file and access WP via the host name, I get the same result.

References I can find are mostly to do with running WP behind a reverse proxy. But I'm not doing that -- unless something in my Vagrant setup means I really am and just don't know it.

Any ideas?

Comment: The point is that something, I think WordPress, is redirecting my request to port 8080 and I don't want it to. Requests for other resources are NOT redirected -- they work. Requests for WordPress resources are redirected to 8080 and they fail. I need to find out what is redirecting WordPress requests to 8080, and make it stop :-)

Comment: Can you post a copy of your Vagrantfile? Port 8080 may be coming in to play from a proxy or WordPress configuration that just needs to be adjusted.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use port 8080 both in the guest and the server. Configure the webserver to listen on port 8080 and map that port to Vagrant host via forwarded_port.